# Angular.js Handle data in frontend or backend only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I want to create a ToDo list using angular. I have a REST API that stores the items in db and provides basic operations. Now when I want to connect my angular app to the REST api I found two ways to do so following some tutorials online:

1.Data gets handled in backend only: A service gets created that has a getAllTodos function. This function gets directly attached to scope (e.g. to use it in ng-repeat):

```
var getAllTodos = function() {
    //Todo: Cache http request
    return $http...;
}
var addTodo = function(todo) {
    //Todo: Clear cache of getAllTodos
    $http...
}
```

2.Data gets handled in frontend too. There is a init function that initializes the todo variable in the service.

```
var todos = [];

var init = function() {
    $http...
    todos = //result of $http;
};

var getAllTodos = function() {
    return todos;
};

var addTodo = function(todo) {
     $http...
     todos.push(todo);
}
```

I've seen both ways in several tutorials but I'm wondering what would be the best way? The first one is used in many tutorials where the author from the start has in mind to attach it to a REST API. The second one is often used when the author at first wants to create the functionality in the frontend and later wants to store data permanently using a backend.

Both ways have its advantages and disadvantages. The first one reduces code duplication in frontend and backend, the second one allows faster operations because it can be handled frontend first and the backend can be informed about changed afterwards.

//EDIT: Frontend is Angular.JS Client for me, backend the REST API on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of Frontend and Backend is often done for security reasons. You can locate Backend on a separate machine and then restrict access to that machine to only calls originating from the Frontend. The theory is that if the Frontend is compromised, the Backend has a lower risk factor. In reality if someone has compromised any machine on your network then the entire network is at risk on one level or another.

Another reason for a Backend/Frontend separation would be to provide database access through the Backend to multiple frontend clients. You have a single Backend with access to the DB and either multiple copies of the Frontend or different Frontends that access the Backend.

Your final design needs to take into account the possible security risks and also deployment and versioning. With the multiple-tier approach you can deploy individual Frontends without having to drop the Backend, and you can also "relocate" parts of the application without downtime. The more flexible the design of your application, the deployment may be more complicated. The needs of your application will depend on if you are writing a simple Blog or a large Enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

You need frontend and backend functionality. In frontend you preprape data which are being send and in the backend you make request to server.